# What plant-based (non-dairy) milk do not separate when making caffe latte?

Tags: substitutions, coffee, vegan, soymilk

This is a little subjective, but what plant-based milk is best used to make a latte?

By "best" I mean one that doesn't separate (like plain soy often does) and has a creamy consistency that best resembles dairy.

Preferably this milk should also steam well.

Note that answers on making custom plant-milk recipes are welcome as I know that making your own nut milks can produce a wide variety of consistencies and textures.

Comment: You might consider rephrasing to ask for a non-dairy option that doesn't separate rather than writing the question in terms of "best".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good plant-based milk I've had success with is hemp milk. I'd say try coconut and almond milk, but these two are thinner in my experience, and tend to be less creamy. Hemp milk foams well, and is quite tasty. Like most things, don't get it too hot, or it'll break and be less desirable. That said, I never have problems in this regard with soy milk, but using non-soy is probably better for many other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Product availability differs wildly from country to country, but in Sweden we have an oat milk specifically made for latte. It's called "iKaffe", which translates to "inCoffee", and is produced by [Oatly](http://www.oatly.com/products/sweden/ikaffe/).

Presumably in response to this product, multinational plant milk giant Alpro [launched a foamable soy milk earlier this year](http://www.mynewsdesk.com/se/alpro/pressreleases/alpro-i-kaffe-perfekt-kaffe-varje-gaang-1796780). It, too, works very well.

The most obvious thing that stands out with these compared to the "normal" milks of their respective brand is that they contain a lot more fat.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with almond milk, both for latte and cappuccino. Just make sure it doesn't boil same as in any other milk.